# What happens to downloaded files if a package install through pip fails midway after downloading a few files due to some reason?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, pip

Do these files get deleted automatically or are they stored in a particular location? I tried downloading a package through pip which failed after downloading a few files. Now I want to know how to get rid of these downloaded files if they have not automatically been deleted due to the failure. Since the package has not been installed, I cannot `pip uninstall` it. I did a basic file search using the name of the package (tickeys)and the result was a single file named tickeys.log . Can I be sure that no other file downloaded during the installation of the package is remaining?

```
$ pip install tickeys
Collecting tickeys
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading tickeys-0.2.5.tar.gz (5.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.3MB 179kB/s 
Collecting cython==0.20.2 (from tickeys)
  Downloading Cython-0.20.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.9MB 215kB/s 
Collecting kivy==1.9.0 (from tickeys)
  Downloading Kivy-1.9.0.tar.gz (16.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 16.2MB 76kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Cython is missing, its required for compiling kivy !


    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-iseWBO/kivy/setup.py", line 173, in <module>
        from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
    ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-iseWBO/kivy/
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: Hi, is it okay now? Although I would still like to know how to get rid of the files, if any.

Comment: No, that part was fine. I meant to refer to the part in your title "apt-get, pip, etc" which covers multiple unrelated tools and "etc" even has an unlimited scope. You're welcome to ask closely related questions but asking the same question about multiple unrelated subjects does not make it a single question or multiple related question.

Comment: It really depends on what package you are trying to install, how you installed it, and the error message. Generally, however, you can not simply start deleting things without causing problems. You need to post all the information including package , where you got it from, the command you ran, and the full output of the command you ran.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer for `apt-get`. From `man apt-get`:

```
clean
    clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files.
    It removes everything but the lock file from
    /var/cache/apt/archives/ and /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.

--- *snip* ---

/var/cache/apt/archives/
    Storage area for retrieved package files. Configuration Item:
    Dir::Cache::Archives.

/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/
    Storage area for package files in transit. Configuration Item:
    Dir::Cache::Archives (partial will be implicitly appended)
```

Thus, partially downloaded files through `apt-get` reside in `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial` and can be removed with the `clean` operation.